# Hidden fragments is an android design pattern?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I am looking at Facebook Android SDK examples, and I have encountered this strange pattern (in Scrumptious example): *all (or almost) the screens of the app are fragments, loaded into the application at the beginning but hidden.*

Later (resume, Session updates, eccetera) one fragment at time is showed, while all the others remain hidden.

This way there is just 1 activity and all the application screens are present at the same time on the activity, just hidden rather than displayed.

Is this some kind of design pattern for Android? Pros & Cons?

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), but maybe not. Are the fragments loaded all at once in the background (while hidden) or are they loaded when a user chooses to reveal them?

Comment: It's not lazy loading, the fragments are loaded, they are just hidden until it's their moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call that a design pattern, but yes - this is quite common.

The main issue with layout inflating is that it may take a lot of time. Keeping the screens prepared reduces the time needed to switch them. It also eliminates the animation hiccup - the main user experience killer. With Material Design in mind this becomes quite important.

The obvious problem with such approach is the memory usage. Facebook displays a lot of data as lists, so I guess they clear all adapters except the one visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Like the activity the Fragments are also having their own life cycles.
They become active when they are attached to the activity and until the 
de-attach. So this is design pattern is introduced by the Android and also fine to use instead of using the different activity for the screens.
The Navigation drawer pattern , given as a example on the developers site is also using the same approach. There are more examples where android has followed the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

From [Android Developers Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

A Fragment should always be piece of one Activity, you can have 1 Activity   with a lot of fragments but that's not a good design for you application, if you are using fragments all the heavy logic has to be done in the Activity and fragments should only hold the proper logic to present and manipulate the data they contain.

In general, practice good **MVC**. Activities should just take data from the models and insert them into the views(fragments), or take events from a view(fragment) and tell the data to do something. Don't run URL requests or other raw data fetches in controllers, and obviously don't run heavy logic in fragments. Hope it help you...